# log4j2 shutdownHook="disable" not working

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I have the shutdownhook error in my Spring boot application in which i use log4j2.

I saw that it was a bug in log4j2 and shutdownHook="disable" was suppossed to resolve it. But inspite of using the same i still get the same error.

I am using spring boot version 1.3.7.RELEASE and the dependecy for log4j2 is 
spring-boot-starter-log4j2 .

Error which i get whetry to close the session using Ctrl-C

```
2016-08-23 13:38:56,098 Thread-7 ERROR No log4j2 configuration file found. Using
 default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
2016-08-23 13:38:56,105 Thread-7 FATAL Unable to register shutdown hook because
JVM is shutting down. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add new shutdown h
ook as this is not started. Current state: STOPPED
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.ad
dShutdownCallback(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:113)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.addShutdownCal
lback(Log4jContextFactory.java:271)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setUpShutdownHook(LoggerC
ontext.java:256)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:
216)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log
4jContextFactory.java:146)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log
4jContextFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:185)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(Abstrac
tLoggerAdapter.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFac
tory.java:43)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(Abstract
LoggerAdapter.java:42)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFact
ory.java:29)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
        at com.worldline.frm.dataloader.policy.CustomQueueRoutePolicy.onStop(Cus
tomQueueRoutePolicy.java:90)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.doStop(RouteService.java:249)
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you register the shutdownHook?

Comment: I have not registered any shutdownhook yet . Do i need to ?  . I thought disabling shutdown hook option tell log4j2 not to invoke shutdown , atleast as per docs.

Comment: Oh, then I misinterpreted the question. From the stacktrace it seems that it is tried to register one, while the app is already shutting down.